# python freezes with many repeated pandas calls

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, freeze

I'm trying to compute the variance of a time series for many sampling frequencies (the so called signature plot), I used the resample method looping on a set of frequencies but python stops before completing the task (no errors, just freezed).
Here the code is

```
var_list = [timeseries.resample(rule=str(int(freq))+'min',how='first').var() for i in np.linspace(2,20,10)]
```

Note that with one less iteration everything is fine (beside memory and cpu usage is very low, I can't see why it doesn't succeed with one more)

[EDIT]
http://www.filedropper.com/14081

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="/media/snake91/01D05438A403F9501/Econometrics/"+datatype+"/"+csvinfile+".csv", sep=',',
                         decimal='.',usecols=["Date","Time","Close"], keep_date_col=True)
data['DateTime'] = data.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date']+ ' ' + row['Time'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'), axis=1)
data.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

price = data["Close"]
```

I'm using only the 'Close' column

[EDIT 2]
After keeping trying I got this

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000030ba810 ***
```

is there a bug?

Comment: can you provide some example data ...

Comment: added, there are only 1098 entries actually...
[EDIT] added also the code I used for parsing

Comment: Is this spam for minibox - I cannot download - and I am not signing up?

Comment: just the first that has come to mind...anyway, I replaced with another one (it shouldn't need registration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks a little complicated ... I hope my simplification is this what you need ...

```
# get an index of pandas Timestamps
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time)

# get the column we want as a pandas Series called price
price = df['Close']
```

**Update**

```
# use a list comprehension to construct a list of variances, 
#    for the various resampling periods
var_list = [price.resample(str(int(i))+'min', how='first').var() 
    for i in np.linspace(2,20,10)]
```

Which yielded ...

```
In [10]: var_list
Out[10]: 
[0.077889810612269461,
 0.077385129726302446,
 0.079956521234607447,
 0.077604408646643086,
 0.077813415563354235,
 0.080675086585717218,
 0.074652971598985707,
 0.0763870569776786,
 0.076195162549351256,
 0.076852363707017035]
```

In dictionary form ...

```
In [11]: %paste
# use a comprehension to construct a dictionary, each entry of which
#    has the variance for each resampling period
var_dic = {i: price.resample(str(int(i))+'min', how='first').var() 
    for i in np.linspace(2,20,10)}
## -- End pasted text --

In [12]: var_dic
Out[12]: 
{2.0: 0.077889810612269461,
 4.0: 0.077385129726302446,
 6.0: 0.079956521234607447,
 8.0: 0.077604408646643086,
 10.0: 0.077813415563354235,
 12.0: 0.080675086585717218,
 14.0: 0.074652971598985707,
 16.0: 0.0763870569776786,
 18.0: 0.076195162549351256,
 20.0: 0.076852363707017035}
```

Comment: how should I interpret 'how=np.var'? the output is another time series, I need one unique value (per frequency), the variance at a given sampling frequency

Comment: My bad ... hopefully fixed